# How can I use enums in structopt?

Tags: enums, rust, command-line-arguments, structopt

I'd like to make `StructOpt` work with enums such that every time a user passes `-d sunday` it'd parsed as a `Day::Sunday`:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate structopt;

use std::path::PathBuf;
use structopt::StructOpt;

// My enum
enum Day {
    Sunday, Monday
}

#[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
#[structopt(name = "example", about = "An example of StructOpt usage.")]
struct Opt {
    /// Set speed
    #[structopt(short = "s", long = "speed", default_value = "42")]
    speed: f64,
    /// Input file
    #[structopt(parse(from_os_str))]
    input: PathBuf,
    /// Day of the week
    #[structopt(short = "d", long = "day", default_value = Day::Monday)]
    day: Day,
}

fn main() {
    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", opt);
}
```

My current *best* solution is to use `Option<String>` as a type and pass a custom `parse_day()`:

```
fn parse_day(day: &str) -> Result<Day, ParseError> {
    match day {
        "sunday" => Ok(Day::Sunday),
        _ => Ok(Day::Monday)
    }
    Err("Could not parse a day")
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Struct-opt accepts any type which implements [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html), which is not far away from your `parse_day` function:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

// any error type implementing Display is acceptable.
type ParseError = &'static str;

impl FromStr for Day {
    type Err = ParseError;
    fn from_str(day: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match day {
            "sunday" => Ok(Day::Sunday),
            "monday" => Ok(Day::Monday),
            _ => Err("Could not parse a day"),
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, the `default_value` should be a string, which will be interpreted into a `Day` using `from_str`.

```
#[structopt(short = "d", long = "day", default_value = "monday")]
day: Day,
```

Comment: At least with Rust 1.46, `ParseError` doesn't look like it exists(?).

Comment: "ParseError" does not work as of rust 1.46>, how would I implement this solution nowadays? What can I replace ParseError with in this scenario?

Answer (score 21):

[@kennytm's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54687863/155423) works, but the `arg_enum!` macro is a more concise way of doing it, as demonstrated in [this example from `structopt`](https://github.com/TeXitoi/structopt/blob/0c888e962d842f2c90c6c290d3a2a40947b37005/examples/enum_in_args.rs):

```
arg_enum! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    enum Day {
        Sunday,
        Monday
    }
}

#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
struct Opt {
    /// Important argument.
    #[structopt(possible_values = &Day::variants(), case_insensitive = true)]
    i: Day,
}

fn main() {
    let opt = Opt::from_args();
    println!("{:?}", opt);
}
```

This will let you parse weekdays as `Sunday` or `sunday`.

Answer (score 6):

The error message is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Day: std::str::FromStr` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:22:17
   |
22 | #[derive(Debug, StructOpt)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::str::FromStr` is not implemented for `Day`
   |
   = note: required by `std::str::FromStr::from_str`
```

You can fix that either by implementing `FromStr` for `Day` (see [kennytm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54687863/493729)), as the message suggests, or by defining a parse function for `Day`:

```
fn parse_day(src: &str) -> Result<Day, String> {
    match src {
        "sunday" => Ok(Day::Sunday),
        "monday" => Ok(Day::Monday),
        _ => Err(format!("Invalid day: {}", src))
    }
}
```

And specifying it with the `try_from_str` attribute:

```
/// Day of the week
#[structopt(short = "d", long = "day", parse(try_from_str = "parse_day"), default_value = "monday")]
day: Day,
```

Comment: Best answer of all! Just missing case-insensivity :)

Comment: @decades case-insensitivity wasn't mentioned in the question and it's just one extra attribute to enable that.

Comment: I solved it like so: match src.to_lowercase().as_ref() {...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `arg_enum!` has been deprecated with `clap 3` coming out, [see the doc here](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap). I just refactored to use clap directly instead of `StructOpts`, it seems that they have been merged.

In your `Cargo.toml` you no longer need StructOpt anymore:

```
clap = { version = "3.1.17", features = ["derive"] }
```

In your `main.rs`, you will now use `clap` with the built in struct opt, note the documentation on the fields becomes the fields helper message value which is neat:

```rs
use clap::StructOpt;

#[derive(clap::ArgEnum, Debug, Clone)]
enum PossibleWords {
    Hello,
    World,
}

#[derive(Debug, clap::Parser, Clone)]
#[clap(long_about = "The worst Hello World!!! App in the world!")]
pub struct Args {
    /// You can't have everything in life, which word should we print?
    #[clap(arg_enum, long, default_value_t = YourEnum::Hello)]
    word: PossibleWords,

    //// Exclamation marks are included FOR FREE with the word of your choice.
    #[clap(long, default_value_t = 10)]
    number_of_exclamation_marks: u64,
}

pub fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();
}
```